# Chaquopy not using correct build path

Tags: chaquopy

When presented with the build path in gradle.build the version provided does not match the runtime version:

```
buildPython "/anaconda3/envs/tensorflow_p35/bin/python3.5"
```

During runtime I print the version as:

```
I/python.stdout: 3.6.5
```

I summon you @mhsmith wherever you are!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`buildPython` is your local copy of Python used during the build, e.g. when running pip. This is different to the Android-based copy of Python used during runtime, which is supplied by Chaquopy and is currently always version 3.6.5.